# The translation of そんな謙遜ともとれる

Tags: translation

> そんな謙遜ともとれる妹の態度に

I have a doubt on how to translate this part of the sentence properly, so I was hoping for confirmation.

とれる can be translated into many words, but the closest meaning to the sentence (in my interpretation) would be: 1. to be interpreted as, and 2. collected.

If とれる is valid to be translated as a part of an attitude/manner, there is a collected manner (calm, cool, composed, etc.)

And I paid attention to the particle と and も that can be translated as (and also).

So my translation is:

> ...from such a humble and also calm attitude of his younger sister.

Did I translate the sentence properly?

Thank you for your kind guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

そんな modifies （妹の）態度, not 謙遜.
謙遜ともとれる is a relative clause that modifies （妹の）態度.

As you know, とれる is the potential form of とる（取る）, and you're right that the とれる here means "interpret", or "see/consider/take". (It's not the とる in 態度をとる in the sense of "to behave", though.)

The と means "as", as in 「AをBととる」 "interpret/take/see/consider A as B". も means "also" or "even.

So your phrase:

> そんな［謙遜ともとれる］（妹の）態度に

means "toward (my/the) sister's such attitude/behavior [which can also/even be interpreted/taken as humility/modesty]" or "toward (my/the) sister's behavior [which can even/also be seen humble/modest]".

Comment: Thank you, now I can understand とれる much better. You are always helpful, thank you once again.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be almost there. Just a few things to point out.

> そんな謙遜ともとれる妹の態度(に)

In order to be able to tell you exactly what the に at the end of your phrase is doing, we'd need the rest of the sentence.

> とれる can be translated into many words, but the closest meaning to the sentence (in my interpretation) would be: 1. to be interpreted as, and 2. collected.

Depending on context, とれる can translate as "be collected" in the sense of gathering something. (この川でとれた鮎 - the 鮎 collected/caught in this river; 裏の畑でとれたばかりのトマトを使用しております - We use tomatoes collected (picked) fresh from the field out back)

However, here, とれる is the 可能形 of とる and here simply means "can take (as)", or "can interpret (as)"

> And I paid attention to the particle と and も that can be translated as (and also).

Be careful here. と is used in the same sense as "and" is in English ONLY when *connecting* nouns. Here it acts as the "(as)" in "can take (as)" and "can interpret (as)"; it's esentially defining the contents of the interpretation. By adding "も" after "と" we indicate that this is not the only thing it can be taken "as" (it can/could be taken as something else *also*). So 謙遜ともとれる on its own translates roughly to:

"(I/we) could also interpret as humility"

You seem to have correctly interpreted that "謙遜ともとれる" is directly modifying "妹の態度". Putting these together, we get, in slightly strange English:

"My younger sister's attitude that I/we could also take as humility".

rephrasing this into more natural English, I might say:

"The seemingly-humble attitutude of my younger sister"

> So my translation is:
>
> ...from such a humble and also calm attitude of his younger sister.

While そんな does translate as "such", this is more in the sense of "that kind of". (In impolite speech, we do sometimes use そんな in the same sense as そんなに (i.e. "to that extent"), but that's not how it's being used here, it is being used to modify 妹の態度)

So if I were to translate your full sentence I might say:

"That seemingly-humble attitutude of my younger sister"

Comment: Thank you, I did read the meaning of そんな, and just like you said it can be translated to other words than 'such'. I used 'such' since I thought とれる can be translated as a behavior kind of words. I still often confuse on the particles, and I learnt something new from you today. Thank you once again.