What is the nuance of 取らない in this sentence? What does it mean?


「つまり学園内で何かあったとしても、病院に運び込むつもりはない。全て学園内で処理すると最初から決まっていた故の設備の充実とも取れねぇか」


つまり学園内で何かあったとしても、病院に運び込むつもりはない

In the first part of the sentence, the character subscribes the theory that no matter what happens, the school won't take them to the hospital.
Then he adds:

全て学園内で処理すると最初から決まっていた故の設備の充実

My reading "全て学園内で処理すると最初から決まっていた故" due to the fact everything must be handled from the facility from the beginning "設備の充実" the equipment is enough
But what is this use とも取れねぇか? It seems to be used for handing out a conclusion similar to "don't you think" in English?

Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72632/5010

The sentence 設備の充実とも取れねぇか can be interpreted as:

"It can be taken to mean the facilities are well equipped, right?".

The conclusion is similar to the "don't you think?" expression with the difference that とも取れる is referring to something previously said, in this case the decision to manage everything within the school.
